# Set insets of programmatically created UITextView

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I've created a UITextView programmatically, but unfortunately it doesn't behave the way a textview does when you drag it from the attributes inspector to the Main.storyboard.
For example: the text in my programmatically created textview doesn't "break line" at the right side of the textview frame.
Although the documentation mentions textContainerInsets, I can't seem to get it to work. (Xcode doesn't recognise the attribute)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {


let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
var textView:UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view = self.scrollView

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height;      

    //Create textview
    let textView : UITextField = UITextField(frame : CGRect(x:10, y:(screenHeight/2), width:        (screenWidth-20), height: (screenHeight/3) ))
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor( red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue:0.9, alpha: 1.0 )
    textView.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("Start typing...", comment: "")   
    textView.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line;
    //   textView.autocorrectionType = .Yes
    self.view.addSubview( textView )

}
```

Is there any way to make the text inside my textview act like normal? multi line instead of one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a `UITextField` in your code, not a `UITextView`.

This:

```
let textView : UITextField = UITextField(frame : CGRect(x:10, y:(screenHeight/2), width:(screenWidth-20), height: (screenHeight/3) ))
```

Should be:

```
let textView : UITextView = UITextView(frame : CGRect(x:10, y:(screenHeight/2), width:        (screenWidth-20), height: (screenHeight/3) ))
```

You also seem to have declared `textView` as a property in your class, so your probably don't want the `let` in there:

```
textView = UITextView(frame : CGRect(x:10, y:(screenHeight/2), width:        (screenWidth-20), height: (screenHeight/3) ))
```

Comment: I do feel stupid now... how could I have missed that :S Thank You!

Comment: It happens to us all :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would implement your UITextView programatically -

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();

    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds;
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height;

    //Create textview
    let textView : UITextView = UITextView(frame : CGRect(x:      10,
                                                          y:      (screenHeight/2),
                                                          width:  (screenWidth-20),
                                                          height: (screenHeight/3)));

    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor( red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue:0.9, alpha: 1.0 );

    textView.text = NSLocalizedString("Start typing... maybe...", comment: "");

    //textView.borderStyle:  border's are not supported by the UITextView

    self.view.addSubview(textView);

    return;
}
```